# simplify using the difference quotient when $f(x)=2/x^2$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to simplify a difference quotient with the form 
$$\frac{f(x+h)-f(h)}/{h}$$
if $f(x)=2/x^2$
I have attempted to cancel out the denominator of the numerator by the least common denominator method. I know that I can solve this using implicit differentiation, but am trying to use the difference quotient to get  the partial derivative

Here is my work so far:

$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{(h)}$

$= \frac{f(2/(x+h)^2) - f(2/x^2)}{h}$

$= \frac{(2/(x+h)^2)-(2/x^2)}{h}$

here I multiply by the LCD

$= \frac{(2(x^2)- 2(x+h)^2)/(x^2(x+h)^2)}{h}$

Here I expand out the top and cancel out $2x^2$

$= \frac{(2x^2 - (2x^2 + 4xh +2h^2))/(x^2(x+h)^2)}{h}$

$= \frac{-(4xh +2h^2)/(x^2(x+h)^2))}{h}$

Here I think I should multiply by $1/h$ to get rid of the $h$ on the bottom

I end up with:

$= \frac{4xh +2h^2}{hx^2(x+h)^2}$

factor out an h

$= \frac{-4x+2h}{x^2(x+h)^2}$

I am not sure about this, or if I can go further? Any advice appreciated!

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: You should have $$\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} = \frac{\dfrac{2}{(x + h)^2} - \dfrac{2}{x^2}}{h}$$ That is, the first line is equal to the third line, but it is not equal to the second line since $$f\left(\frac{2}{x^2}\right) = \frac{2}{\left(\dfrac{2}{x^2}\right)^2} = \frac{2}{\left(\dfrac{4}{x^4}\right)} = \frac{x^4}{2}$$

Comment: Is there a nice way for me to use the mathjax formatting? I am not familiar with the language that it uses, perhaps there is a convert tool?

Comment: The links Chantry Cargill suggested are good. I Also like [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Mathematics) and [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics).

Comment: To get started try a latex equation editor such as  http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php, and just play "cause and effect". You can see the output as well as that code generated.

Answer (score 2):

> factor out an h
>
> $= \frac{-4x+2h}{x^2(x+h)^2}$

First of all you should allways write $\lim_{h \to 0}$, if h is a part of your term. Out of this, it looks fine.

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-4x+2h}{x^2(x+h)^2}$$

Multiplying out the brackets in the denominator.

$$=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{-4x+2h}{x^2(x^2+2xh+h^2)}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{-4x+2h}{x^4+2x^3h+x^2h^2}$$

All terms with the factor h, goes to 0, if h goes to zero.

$$=\frac{-4x}{x^4}$$

cancelling out x

$$=\frac{-4}{x^3}$$

Comment: Ok, so it looks like I was kind of on the right track. If I am not given a limit and need to simplify the difference quotient should I leave it at the last step before setting h = to 0?

Comment: If the limit for h is not given, then you should define h as $x_1-x_0=h$ In this case you do not need $\lim_{h \to 0}$ and you do not need the last to steps.